# Can't access/update class object properties after creation - javascript

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

The problem is I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: holder is not defined" when trying to access object properties after object creation.

I'm doing the To Do List project for the the Odin Project.
JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/appredator/8tcg7yo9/312/

Essentially, I want to click the add button, gather the values from the input fields, and save the values to their correct properties in a corresponding object and then display them as well.

```
   //HTML

    <div class="grid-container">
    <h2 class="projectName">
    Project
    </h2>
    <h2 class="task">
    Task
    </h2>
    <h2 class="dueDate">
    Due Date
    </h2>
    <h2 class="status">
    Status
    </h2>
    </div>
    <!-- End Header Div -->
    
    <!-- Begin To Do List Grid Rows -->
    <div class="projects">
    
    </div>
    
    <!-- Button at bottom of page -->
    <button id="addProject">
    Add To Do 
    </button>
```

//JS

```
class Project {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
  
}

class ToDo {

  constructor(projectName, task, dueDate, status) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.task = task;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.status = status; 
    this.list = 
    [{
    task: "",
    status: "",
    dueDate: "",
    }]; 
    
    }

}


// Add Project Button Logic

const addButton = document.querySelector("#addProject");
addButton.addEventListener('click', addProject);

function addProject(){

let counter = 0;
//Select bottom div for updates etc
var content = document.querySelector(".projects");

//Save projectNameField contents when enter is pressed on the ProjectName Field
const projectNameField = document.createElement("input");
projectNameField.classList.add('projectNameCell');
content.appendChild(projectNameField);
projectNameField.addEventListener('keydown', function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === 'Tab') {
//Get and save project name
/* var project = projectNameField.value; */
//Instantiate Project constructor with DOM value
let project = new Project(projectNameField.value);
console.log(e.key)

projectNameField.remove();
//Use constructor to display project name in text
const projectNameDisplay = document.createElement("h3");
projectNameDisplay.classList.add('projectNameCell');
projectNameDisplay.innerHTML = project.name;
content.appendChild(projectNameDisplay);

}
});


//Save titleField contents when enter is pressed on the ProjectName Field
const taskField = document.createElement("input");
taskField.classList.add('taskCell');
content.appendChild(taskField);
taskField.addEventListener('keydown', function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === 'Tab')  {
//Get and save title
//Instantiate toDo constructor with DOM value
let holder = new ToDo(taskField.value);
holder.projectName = document.querySelector(".projectNameCell").innerHTML;
holder.task = taskField.value;
console.log(holder.task)
//Use constructor to display project name in text
const taskDisplay = document.createElement("h3");
taskDisplay.classList.add('titleCell');
taskDisplay.innerHTML = holder.task;
taskField.remove();
content.appendChild(taskDisplay);

}
});

const dueDateField = document.createElement("input");
dueDateField.classList.add('dueDateCell');
content.appendChild(dueDateField);
dueDateField.addEventListener('keydown', function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === 'Tab')  {
//Instantiate toDo constructor with DOM value
holder.dueDate = dueDateField.value;
/* console.log(task.list.dueDate) */

dueDateField.remove();
//Use constructor to display project name in text
const dueDateDisplay = document.createElement("h3");
dueDateDisplay.classList.add('dueDateCell');
dueDateDisplay.innerHTML = holder.dueDate;
content.appendChild(dueDateDisplay);

}
});

const statusField = document.createElement("input");
statusField.classList.add('statusCell');
content.appendChild(statusField);
statusField.addEventListener('keydown', function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === 'Tab')  {

//Instantiate toDo constructor with DOM value
task.status = statusField.value;
console.log(task.dueDate)

statusField.remove();
//Use constructor to display project name in text
const statusDisplay = document.createElement("h3");
statusDisplay.classList.add('statusCell');
statusDisplay.innerHTML = task.status;
content.appendChild(statusDisplay);

}
});



counter++;

}
```

```
**I have tried adding get / set methods to the ToDo class with no luck. I also tried factory functions...
This is a scoping problem right? The properties are local scoped to the holder object?... I cut my code down on this post, but the full code is at jsfiddle. The reference error happens after you hit tab or enter on the 3rd input field.... Please advise. I'm kind of puzzled why objects would be so hard to access and update after creation lol. I created the object so I could use it. I know it's something trivial about scope and when to use constructors/classes/factories, but I cant figure it out.**
```

Comment: Please post the entire code of your page, including the html, to make a [mcve].

Comment: No, `holder` is not `undefined` inside that event listener - but notice that it's *only* defined inside of that event listener, and you're not doing anything else with it.

Comment: I've added all my JS and HTML. @Bergi - Thanks for the feedback. I'm new here. If my object construction happens inside the addProject method, why is that a problem? Wouldn't any object that is not hard-coded into the app have to be created when an event or method fires off?